# Get text from popup menu using Python's Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

When you hover over the `i` you get a popup menu.

[image: no hover]

[image: hover]

I want to get the last item of the popup `3,0` using Python's Selenium.

But however, it's not working for me. What do I do wrong?

```
a = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="articlelist"]/form/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/span/div/div[3]/div[2]').text
print(a)
```

HTML Snapshot:
[image: Website code]

Full website code for download: we.tl/t-dZexrOqPU8

Comment: please do not post a picture of the HTML ... post the HTML text instead

Comment: Added the HTML as download :) Thx!

Comment: that is worse ... why should anyone here have to go to another website to see what you are talking about? ... questions here should be self contained ... even the pictures should be added as a picture, not as a link

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow, I can't post pictures directly :/

Comment: @hallowelt444, please post your code in your query. It is generally untrustworthy to download from other website. Hope you can understand. If possible (and if there is no login involved), you may provide the website link too.

Answer (score 0):

To print the text ***3,0*** you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='subinfo']/div[@class='art_popup_infobox']/div[@class='art_popup_line_wrapper'][./div[starts-with(., 'Durchmesser')]]//div[@class='art_popup_info']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally to extract the text ***3,0*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='subinfo']/div[@class='art_popup_infobox']/div[@class='art_popup_line_wrapper'][./div[starts-with(., 'Durchmesser')]]//div[@class='art_popup_info']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55241232/7429447)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55902072/7429447)

Comment: Not working for me :/